# Silverlight Datagrid Column header Text Break Line

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, resourcedictionary

I am Using Silverlght 4.I have a datagrid Header  whose text="StudentDetailOfAplication".Since It Occupies more length in I need to have a break line near "Application".Please send me some usefull links how to do this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="227" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,37,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="316" >
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="StudenDetailsOFApplication" Width="100" Binding="{Binding id}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding productName}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="NumberOfAplication" Width="114"  Binding="{Binding qty}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid></Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Header="Student Details&#10;Of Application"` or `Header="Student Details&#x0a;Of Application"` will also work. Or if you're not inserting into a string you can also do something like.

```
<TextBlock>
Line<LineBreak/>Break
</TextBlock>
```

but personally I just use the codes shown in the first two examples. Also keep in mind the xml will retain whitespace, so you can do like `Header="  Details of&#10;Student Application"` for alignment purposes if TextAlignment property isnt available. Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, we all help each other. Cheers :)